# How can I combine some functors to generate a `isOdd` function?

Tags: c++, stl

How can I combine several functors to generate a `isOdd` functor?

`equal_to`

`modulus`

`bind2nd`

`...`

```
int nums[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
vector<int> v1(nums, nums+5), v2;
remove_copy_if(v1.begin(), v1.end(), back_inserter(v2), isOdd);
```

v2 => {0, 2, 4}

Comment: You do realize that an important characteristic of code is being readable and maintainable, and that this will make the code probably harder to read. If you have a C++0x enabled computer you will be able to make it readable an *local* with lambdas: `remove_copy_if( v.begin(), v.end(), back_inserter(v2), []( int x ) { return x % 2; }` )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using just the primitives provided in the standard libraries, this is actually surprisingly difficult because the binders provided by `bind1st` and `bind2nd` don't allow you to compose functions.  In this particular case, you're trying to check if

```
x % 2 == 1
```

Which, if you consider how the `<functional>` primitives work, is equivalent to

```
equal_to(modulus(x, 2), 1)
```

The problem is that the components in `<functional>` don't allow you to pass the output of one function as the input to another function very easily.  Instead, you'll have to rely on some other technique.  In this case, you could cheat by using two successive applications of `not1`:

```
not1(not1(bind2nd(modulus<int>(), 2)))
```

This works because it's equivalent to

```
!!(x % 2)
```

If x is even, then this is `!!0`, which is `false`, and if x is odd this is `!!1`, which is `true`.  The reason for the double-filtering through `not1` is to ensure that the result has type `bool` rather than `int`, since

```
bind2nd(modulus<int>(), 2)
```

is a function that produces an `int` rather than the `bool` you want.

Comment: Great! `isEven = not1(bind2nd(modulus<int>(), 2))` Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

isOdd can be defined as:

```
bind2nd(modulus<int>(),2)
```